# Multiple choice quiz or exam generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm trying to create a script or app for creating multiple choice quizzes. It would allow the user to enter a question, then give a true answer and a number of answers to choose from. The user could repeat that process as many times as he wishes. Then the user would need to enter the number of questions that the created quiz would have. In the end the quiz would be saved as a pdf or word document. All of this would nee a gui made in Qt. So far I have made most of the quiz script and it is working properly. (still need to figure out how to add a,b,c... in front of answers and save to pdf but that shoudn't be a problem). The gui is also done and I think it should work properly.

The problem is I don't know how to connect the quiz script with the gui. I tried many things and none of them work.

```
import json
import random

def quiz_name():
    name = input('Enter the name of the quiz file: ')
    return name

def question_generator():
    question_text = input('Enter a question. When done entering questions type \'stop\': ')
    if question_text.lower() == 'stop':
        return None

    true = input('Enter the correct answer: ')

    answer_dict = []
    while True:
        answer = input('Enter an answer. When done entering questions type \'stop\': ')
        if answer.lower() == 'stop':
            break
        answer_dict.append(answer)         
    qapair = (question_text, true, answer_dict) 

    return qapair



def question_list_builder():
    questions = []
    while True:
        qg_method = question_generator()
        if qg_method is None:
            break
        q = (qg_method[0], qg_method[1],qg_method[2]) 
        questions.append(q)
    return questions

#lista_pitanja = question_list_builder()

#for lp in lista_pitanja:
#    pitanje=lista_pitanja
#    broj =0
#    while broj <len(lista_pitanja[2]):
#        print(broj+1,+': '+)
#        broj+=1

class ObjectEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
  def default(self, obj):
    return obj.__dict__

if __name__ == '__main__':
    quest = question_list_builder()
    name = quiz_name()
    def JSONWrite(quiz, filepath):
        with open(f'{filepath}.json', 'w') as fp:
            fp.write(quiz)
    print(json.dumps(quest, cls=ObjectEncoder))
#    random.sample(pitanja,4)
    JSONWrite(json.dumps(random.sample(quest,3), cls=ObjectEncoder, indent=4),name)
```

If needed I will paste the gui code

Edit: Added the gui code

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1077, 943)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.line_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.line_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_3.setObjectName("line_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.line_3, 0, 4, 1, 1)
        self.line_4 = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.line_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.VLine)
        self.line_4.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_4.setObjectName("line_4")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.line_4, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.Answer_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.Answer_btn.setObjectName("Answer_btn")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.Answer_btn, 4, 2, 1, 1)
        self.LE_datName = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.LE_datName.setObjectName("LE_datName")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.LE_datName, 7, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_datName = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_datName.setObjectName("label_datName")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_datName, 7, 0, 1, 1)
        self.Question_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.Question_btn.setObjectName("Question_btn")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.Question_btn, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        self.LE_TAnswer = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.LE_TAnswer.setObjectName("LE_TAnswer")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.LE_TAnswer, 3, 1, 1, 1)
        self.LE_Answer = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.LE_Answer.setObjectName("LE_Answer")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.LE_Answer, 4, 1, 1, 1)
        self.line_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.line_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_2.setObjectName("line_2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.line_2, 8, 0, 1, 4)
        self.label_NQuestion = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_NQuestion.setObjectName("label_NQuestion")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_NQuestion, 9, 0, 1, 1)
        self.label_Answer = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_Answer.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.label_Answer.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.AutoText)
        self.label_Answer.setScaledContents(False)
        self.label_Answer.setObjectName("label_Answer")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_Answer, 4, 0, 1, 1)
        self.LE_NQuestions = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.LE_NQuestions.setObjectName("LE_NQuestions")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.LE_NQuestions, 9, 1, 1, 1)
        self.New_Question_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.New_Question_btn.setObjectName("New_Question_btn")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.New_Question_btn, 4, 3, 1, 1)
        self.TAnswer_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.TAnswer_btn.setObjectName("TAnswer_btn")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.TAnswer_btn, 3, 2, 1, 1)
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.line, 6, 0, 1, 4)
        self.Dat_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.Dat_btn.setObjectName("Dat_btn")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.Dat_btn, 7, 2, 1, 1)
        self.label_TAnswer = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_TAnswer.setObjectName("label_TAnswer")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_TAnswer, 3, 0, 1, 1)
        self.Generate_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.Generate_btn.setObjectName("Generate_btn")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.Generate_btn, 9, 3, 1, 1)
        self.NQuestion_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.NQuestion_btn.setObjectName("NQuestion_btn")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.NQuestion_btn, 9, 2, 1, 1)
        self.LE_Question = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.LE_Question.setToolTipDuration(-1)
        self.LE_Question.setText("")
        self.LE_Question.setObjectName("LE_Question")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.LE_Question, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.Done_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.Done_btn.setObjectName("Done_btn")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.Done_btn, 5, 2, 1, 1)
        self.line_okv2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.line_okv2.setLineWidth(5)
        self.line_okv2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_okv2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_okv2.setObjectName("line_okv2")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.line_okv2, 10, 0, 1, 4)
        self.line_okv1 = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.line_okv1.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line_okv1.setLineWidth(3)
        self.line_okv1.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line_okv1.setObjectName("line_okv1")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.line_okv1, 0, 0, 1, 4)
        self.label_Question = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_Question.setObjectName("label_Question")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_Question, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.gridLayout_2, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        self.Answer_btn.pressed.connect(self.LE_Answer.clear)
        self.New_Question_btn.clicked.connect(self.LE_Question.clear)
        self.New_Question_btn.clicked.connect(self.LE_TAnswer.clear)
        self.New_Question_btn.clicked.connect(self.LE_Answer.clear)
        self.Generate_btn.clicked.connect(self.LE_NQuestions.clear)
        self.Generate_btn.clicked.connect(self.LE_datName.clear)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Kolokvij"))
        self.Answer_btn.setText(_translate("Form", "Enter Answer"))
        self.label_datName.setText(_translate("Form", "Enter the name of the file:"))
        self.Question_btn.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "Pritisnite ovo"))
        self.Question_btn.setText(_translate("Form", "Enter Question"))
        self.label_NQuestion.setText(_translate("Form", "Number of questions in exam:"))
        self.label_Answer.setText(_translate("Form", "Enter all the possible answers:"))
        self.New_Question_btn.setText(_translate("Form", "New Question"))
        self.TAnswer_btn.setText(_translate("Form", "Enter T Answer"))
        self.Dat_btn.setText(_translate("Form", "Enter"))
        self.label_TAnswer.setText(_translate("Form", "Enter the corect answer:"))
        self.Generate_btn.setText(_translate("Form", "Create exam"))
        self.NQuestion_btn.setText(_translate("Form", "Enter"))
        self.LE_Question.setToolTip(_translate("Form", "Unesite pitanje te pritisnite dugme Unesi pitanje"))
        self.Done_btn.setText(_translate("Form", "Done"))
        self.label_Question.setText(_translate("Form", "Enter a question:"))





    def quiz_name(self):
        name = self.LE_datName.text()
        return name

    def question_generator(self):
        question_text = self.LE_Question.text()
        if question_text.lower() == self.New_Question_btn.clicked.connect(self.question_generator):
            return None

        true = self.LE_TAnswer.text()

        answer_dict = []
#        while True:
        answer = self.LE_Answer.text()
#            if answer.lower() == 'stop':
#                break
        answer_dict.append(answer)         
        qapair = (question_text, true, answer_dict) 

        return qapair,print (qapair)

    def question_list_builder(self):
        questions = []
        while True:
            qg_method = self.question_generator()
            if qg_method is None:
                break
            q = (qg_method[0], qg_method[1],qg_method[2]) 
            questions.append(q)
        return questions

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Paste the GUI code.

Comment: you can make a process call to execute the script somewhere in your Gui (like when a button is clicked) or better yet make the script a class and import it & use it in your gui.

Comment: I tried adding functions from the script one by one and connecting them with the gui but it didnt work. My knowledge of python is a bit limited :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has serious logic, conceptual and programming issues.

First of all: even if it doesn't seem very important, *never* use variable names that are too similar to built-in types (in your case, `true`). `True` (along with `False`) is a boolean built-in, and using such a name (even with a different casing) might lead to problems with readability and, in the end, debugging.
Always use clear and unique variable names, in your case it might be something like `correctAnswer`.

Second, don't use a while loop when dealing with UI elements. A graphic interface is usually based on an [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) which expects some type of interaction (from the user or the system) and just waits until that happens. Using a while loop (or, for what's worth, *any* kind of looping, including `for` cycles or recursive calls to a function) will block the ability to receive those events, making the interface unusable.

Third; you can't use an `if` statement between a string and the returned value of a connection (which is usually `None`): it's apples and oranges.
When you do `someSignal.connect(someSlot)` you are actually telling Qt that it will have to call that `someSlot` whenever that `someSignal` is emitted.
Imagine something like this:

```
self.fridge.empty.connect(self.goToMall)
```

This will call `goToMall` whenever the fridge says it's empty. Then, suppose you're going on vacation and you don't want to keep your fridge full:

```
self.fridge.empty.disconnect(self.goToMall)
```

As you can see, the `connect` doesn't give you back anything useful for a comparison with a string: it's like saying "check if my name is equal to the fact that I'll go to the mall whenever the fridge is empty".
<sub>Note: the documentation [says](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#connecting-disconnecting-and-emitting-signals) that `connect()` returns a `Connection` object, which can be later used for a disconnection. In the (rather old) version of PyQt I'm using it just returns `None`, but that could have been changed in the meantime. That said, the invalid comparison issue would still exist.</sub>

Fourth, don't return `print()`: it just returns None, that's just unnecessary.

Finally; **never** mix the generated code from `pyuic` for your programs. Leave that py files as they are, and import them as modules as explained [in the documentation](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

---

Now, regenerate the `.ui` file you created with Designer, and use something like this *in another file*, which will be your main program script:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from ui_form import Ui_Form

# I'm using the third method described in the designer documentation given above, 
# the multiple inheritance approach
class QuestionBuilder(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.New_Question_btn.clicked.connect(self.question_generator)

        self.questions = []

    def question_generator(self):
        question_text = self.LE_Question.text()
        # I don't really know what you meant by comparing the string with the
        # connection, I'm assuming you didn't want to add the same question twice
        if self.questions and self.questions[-1].lower() == question_text:
        for existing_questions in self.questions:
            if question_text.lower() == existing_questions[0]:
                print('question already exists, ignoring')
                return

        correctAnswer = self.LE_TAnswer.text()

        answers = []
        answers.append(self.LE_Answer.text())
        self.questions.append((question_text, correctAnswer, answers))

        self.LE_Answer.clear()
        self.LE_Question.clear()
        self.LE_TAnswer.clear()

        print(self.questions)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QuestionBuilder()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Note that in the example above I didn't implement correct answer checking (nor the check for *all* possible answers nor the functions related to the other buttons).

Let me tell you that your approach has several UI problems that might lead you to hard to debug side effects (programmatically and from user experience), and I believe that the most important issue is adding too many buttons with unnecessary functions (and unclear descriptions) that you'll have to account for - not considering creating an interface that is confusing to the final user.
What will you do when the "Enter T answer" is clicked and no question exists? And what if you click "Enter answer" and the valid answer field is empty? What if an answer is similar to another one but with different lettercase, and only one of them is accually correct? How could you really detect and notify the user whenever some field is invalid?

I really believe that you'll need to completely rethink the whole interface *before* writing the actual code, possibly using a dynamic way of adding answers and providing a system that allows the user to select *which one* of them is the correct one.